# Performance Issue - Looping through many xml files

Tags: xml, performance, bash, loops, awk

I have a years worth of daily xml reports and I am trying to go through each one and find the purchase date and determine if it is at least a year older than the date of the file.  If so I write the name of the file and the purchase date to a log.  Problem is the performance is really pretty bad.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *xml ; do
fileDate=`echo ${file} | cut -c 18-35 | sed 's/.xml//'`
fileDateSeconds=`date --date="${fileDate}" +"%s"`
awk '/PurchaseDate/ {print}' ${file} >> /tmp/yamExport/tempFile.txt
cat /tmp/yamExport/tempFile.txt | while read input
do
        lineDate=`echo ${input} | cut -c 15-24`
        lineDateSeconds=`date --date="${lineDate}" +"%s"`
        delta=`expr $fileDateSeconds - $lineDateSeconds`
        if [ "$delta" -gt "31556926" ]
        then
        #echo "$file : $input"
        echo "$file : $input" >> /tmp/yamExport/yamExportTimestamps2.log
        fi
done
done
```

At first I was just looping through the entire file line by line

```
cat ${file} | while read input
do
        if [[ "$input" =~ "PurchaseDate" ]]
        then
```

But then I determined it was faster (but still pretty slow) to use awk to quickly grab all lines with PurchaseDate and output to a temp file and then loop through.  If anybody has any suggestions on how I can improve perf on this it would be very helpful.  Can I operate on the output of the awk statement similar to a loop?  If I could do that I think the perf would be much better.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

writing the awk output to a temp file will certainly kill your performance. Also, you're *appending* to that temp file, so you're processing the results from the first xml file for *every* subsequent xml file.

This code minimizes the number of external processes you need to call

```
for file in *xml ; do
    fileDateSeconds=$(date --date="${file:17:18}" +"%s")
    grep -F 'PurchaseDate' "$file" |
    while read input; do
        lineDateSeconds=$(date --date="${input:14:10}" +"%s")
        if (( (fileDateSeconds - lineDateSeconds) > 31556926 )); then
            echo "$file : $input"
        fi
    done
done > /tmp/yamExport/yamExportTimestamps2.log
```

I changed `awk` to `grep`, which is the more appropriate tool for finding lines in a file.

Moving the redirection to the output file outside of the outer loop should reduce the number of times the file has to be opened.

Comment: Snap! :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: First off, thanks for the suggestions.  I can't believe i overlooked the appending to the temp file, really bad on my part.  Can you explain to me the following for my understanding: $(date --date="${file:17:18}"?  The filename has the format of 12345_export_2013-4-4.xml so it seems that this code doesn't account for the '.xml' at the end and I end up with a "invalid" date format.

Comment: In the meantime I used your suggestions, only keeping my 2 lines where i set fileDate and fileDateSeconds.  The improved speed from your code is significant.  Thanks!  I would be interested if you could elaborate on my other question if you had time.  thank you.

Comment: The form `${var:a:b}` is a substring of $var starting at the a'th char and of length b. Please show a real filename: `12345_export_2013-4-4.xml` does not satisfy `echo ${file} | cut -c 18-35 | sed 's/.xml//'`

Comment: Assuming the file format is "stuff_stuff_date.xml", I would do this: `fileDate=${file##*_}; fileDate=${fileDate%.xml}` -- first strip off everything up to the right-most underscore, then strip off the extension.

Comment: thanks glenn.  you are correct that the filename i provided isn't exactly accurate.  This is a generica filename that fits the mold, so to speak: 123456_abcExport_2013-4-4.xml.  It is not elegant but I know the beginning of the date starts at the 18th char and I just overshoot it in the cut command to make sure i get everything, then strip the '.xml'.  Not pretty and I your suggestions is much better.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *xml ; do
fileDate=`echo ${file} | cut -c 18-35 | sed 's/.xml//'`
fileDateSeconds=`date --date="${fileDate}" +"%s"`
grep PurchaseDate ${file} | while read input
do
    lineDate=`echo ${input} | cut -c 15-24`
    lineDateSeconds=`date --date="${lineDate}" +"%s"`
    delta=$((fileDateSeconds - lineDateSeconds))
    if [ "$delta" -gt "31556926" ]
    then
    echo "$file : $input"
    fi
done
done > /tmp/yamExport/yamExportTimestamps2.log
```

Comment: Some explanatory text would be helpful to highlight your changes.

Comment: I was about to add it as an edit when I saw you had already done such a fine job so I didn't bother and just upvoted your answer!